# trouble with converting values to scientific notation 1e-3 from 0.001 etc

Tags: r

I know that this could be silly question but I think things should be more clear about on this. I mean converting numbers from normal to scientific format for example from usual 0.001 to 1e-3 format.

I know there are some similar questions but the point is I want to do this process without changing global `options(scipen)`. It is not good use always first change `options(scipen)` in my case as other values which I dont want  them to be changed.

Here is what I mean, lets say we have a data like this

```
set.seed(12345)
set =rep(rep(c("1","2"),each=5),times=1)
V=rep(seq(1,1.4,0.1),times=2)
value <- replicate(1,c(replicate(2,sort(10^runif(5,-3,0),decreasing=FALSE))))
data_rep <- data.frame(V, value,set)

#> data_rep
#     V       value set
#1  1.0 0.002351715   1
#2  1.1 0.005382811   1
#3  1.2 0.023703932   1
#4  1.3 0.058314556   1
#5  1.4 0.476184589   1
#6  1.0 0.001595635   2
#7  1.1 0.001896175   2
#8  1.2 0.034667861   2
#9  1.3 0.097931107   2
#10 1.4 0.197982134   2
```

## Trial 1

When we do `options(scipen=-10)`

```
#> data_rep
#         V        value set
#1  1.0e+00 2.341224e-02   1
#2  1.1e+00 1.454493e-01   1
#3  1.2e+00 1.918435e-01   1
#4  1.3e+00 4.239548e-01   1
#5  1.4e+00 4.553797e-01   1
#6  1.0e+00 3.155843e-03   2
#7  1.1e+00 9.446831e-03   2
#8  1.2e+00 3.370335e-02   2
#9  1.3e+00 1.524459e-01   2
#10 1.4e+00 9.315600e-01   2
```

As we can see this time V column also changed which is not good when plotting

```
qplot(data=data_rep,x=V,y=value)
```

[image]

## Trial 2

changing format using `format` function

```
  options(scipen = 0)
    library(dplyr)
    df_format <- data_rep%>%
  mutate(value=as.numeric(format(value,scientific=TRUE,digits=4))) %>%
  mutate(logic=ifelse(value<2e-1,TRUE,FALSE))

#       > df_format
#     V    value set logic
#1  1.0 0.023410   1  TRUE
#2  1.1 0.145400   1  TRUE
#3  1.2 0.191800   1  TRUE
#4  1.3 0.424000   1 FALSE
#5  1.4 0.455400   1 FALSE
#6  1.0 0.003156   2  TRUE
#7  1.1 0.009447   2  TRUE
#8  1.2 0.033700   2  TRUE
#9  1.3 0.152400   2  TRUE
#10 1.4 0.931600   2 FALSE
```

As we can see, value column changed to the original format. how can we keep scientific notation in the `value` column?

Comment: What you should do is to leave scientific notation on and just change the labels programmatically

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All of the established wisdom on this seems to fall into 2 camps. One camp says to use `scipen` in `options`, which you don't like for the reasons you described.

The other solution is to leave scientific notation on and replace the tick mark labels when you go to plot the graph.

You can use `format` with `scientific=F` to create the non-scientific tick mark labels. This guide shows how to customize those labels for different `ggplot2` plots:

http://www.sthda.com/english/wiki/ggplot2-axis-ticks-a-guide-to-customize-tick-marks-and-labels

Comment: yes you are right on this. I know I can change the format for ggplot but I wish to have an alternative without `scipen`.